# Edit the HTML code of the website with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering whether it is legal to change the website's HTML code temporarily?
It is possible to manually edit the scripts of any website however I am not sure if it is possible to automate the process.
Is there any tools, suggestion or directions I can start with?

Comment: https://medium.com/globant/local-overrides-a-smart-add-on-to-chrome-fee3f6993ea0

Comment: yes it is completely legal and just inspect element my man

Comment: @NehanYaser I was wondering whether automating the process is  possible or not? Like simple javascript code which can access web page's script and edit, cut and paste codes.

Comment: @MarkEzberg you can use webscrapping technologies (puppeteer incase of nodejs) to fetch rendered html source but as for the rest youll have to come up with something yourself